# Get clientHeight of content inside custom web-component nested in Polymer paper-dialog

Tags: javascript, html, dialog, polymer, web-component

I''ll try to explain my problem the clearest I can.

I'm using `<paper-dialog>` and `<paper-dialog-scrollable>`.

In `<paper-dialog-scrollable>` I have a form which is a custom `web-component`.

In this form I use an other custom `web-component` which expands and collapses content.

The default state of the content is collapsed.

In the expandcomponent I save the `clientHeight` of the content in a variable `contentHeight` and set the `height` of the content to 0.

I have a function `toggle()` which is executed when a trigger is clicked.

`toggle()` sets the contents `height` to `contentHeight`.

Now this works perfectly when I use my form or the expand component alone, but it doesn't work when they're nested inside a `paper-dialog` because the `clientHeight` is then 0.

Code:

```
<paper-dialog with-backdrop style="min-width: 90%;">
   <paper-dialog-scrollable>
      <my-custom-form-component></my-custom-form-component>
   </paper-dialog-scrollable>
</paper-dialog>
```

Code from `<my-custom-form-component>` :

```
<div id="custom-expand-component-trigger"></div>
<custom-expand-component trigger="custom-expand-component-trigger">
   blabla a lot of content......
</custom-expand-component>
```

`toggle()` function (inside `<custom-expand-component>`):

```
function toggle(){
  if(!that.opened){
    content.style.height = contentHeight + 'px';  //contentHeight is 0 when form is nested in <paper-dialog>
  } else{
    content.style.height = startHeight;
  }
  that.opened = !that.opened;
}
```

Any Ideas how I can get the clientHeight even if my form is inside the dialog?

I hope this is clear enough.

Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clientHeight` of an hidden element is 0 so you cannot get it until it is rendered.

The element is actually rendered first when the `<paper-dialog>` is opened. When it happens, the `iron-overlay-opened` event is fired. That's an opportunity to get the right `clientHeight` if you haven't set it before:

```
myDialog.addEventListener( "iron-overlay-opened", function ()
{
    this.querySelector( "custom-expand-component" ).init()
} )
```

Inside the `init()` method, set the correct values for your private variables:

```
var CEC = Object.create( HTMLElement.prototype )
CEC.createdCallback = function () {
    var that = this
    var startHeight
    var contentHeight 

    this.init = function () {
        if ( !contentHeight ) {
            contentHeight = this.clientHeight + "px"  //OK
            startHeight = this.getAttribute( "start-height" )
            opened = false                  
            this.style.height = startHeight
        }
    }

    document.getElementById( this.getAttribute( "trigger" ) ).onclick = toggle

    function toggle() {
        opened = !opened
        that.style.height = ( opened )? contentHeight : startHeight
    }
}
document.registerElement( "custom-expand-component", { prototype: CEC } )
```

The CSS transition is working now:

```
custom-expand-component {
    display: block ;
    overflow-y: scroll ;
    transition: height 0.5s ;
}
```

Comment: I was using a css animation for expand but I can live without it. Replaced all height with maxHeight and works now. thanks

Comment: Olivier, I've changed my answer to make it transition-compliant. If you like you can upvote ;-)

Comment: Nice, I rewrote it the Polymer way and works perfectly. thanks again